# Generate field from association

Tags: uml, code-generation, acceleo, ocl

I want to generate a field from association.
The problem that I have is that I'm using:

```
[for (p: Property | aClass.getAssociations().ownedEnd -> select(p: Property | p.type <> aClass)) separator('\n')]
    [p.visibility/] [p.type.name/] [p.type.name.toLowerFirst()/];
[/for]

[for (p: Property | aClass.getAssociations().ownedEnd -> select(p: Property | p.type = p.getOtherEnd().type)) separator('\n')]
    [p.visibility/] [p.type.name/] [p.type.name.toLowerFirst()/];
[/for]
```

So that checks for all associations and if the association type isn't the same ass class type it creates a field of that type.
And if the ends are the same type it creates a field of the same type as the class in which it is contained.

So basically if there is association A - B and A - A
For B create A, for A create B and A.
But there is a problem with second loop. It creates two fields instead of one, which is pretty logical. And here comes the question. How I can fix this? I'm not sure if I'm able to declare some kind of variable here and check %2. I can't just take one value, because there could be multiple associations.
Perhaps I did all the thing wrong? Maybe there is a way to iterate over the ends that would save me all those checks and two for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [for (a: Association | aClass.getAssociations())]
        [if a.ownedEnd.type = a.ownedEnd.getOtherEnd().type]
            [a.visibility/] [a.endType.name/] [a.endType.name.toLowerFirst()/];
        [else]
            [for (p: Property | a.ownedEnd -> select (type <> aClass))]
                [p.visibility/] [p.type.name/] [p.type.name.toLowerFirst()/];
            [/for]
        [/if]
    [/for]
```

That seems to do the trick